# Скриншот всей страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Нашел на гитхабе](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright-python#sync-variant) следующий код. Kак я понял, он должен делать скрин всей страницы, но делает только видимой части и не пойму, что не так:

```
with sync_playwright() as p:
for browser_type in [p.chromium, p.firefox, p.webkit]:
    browser = browser_type.launch()
    page = browser.newPage()
    page.goto('http://yandex.ru')
    page.screenshot(path=f'example-{browser_type.name}.png')
    browser.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

А не легче сделать это более доступными модулями?
Пример -

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
import time

# Открываем сайт и браузер
webbrowser.open('https://python.org')
# Ждём пока загрузиться сайт
time.sleep(3)
# Делаем скриншот
pyautogui.press('printscreen')
```

Теперь Ваш скрин у Вас в буфере, нажмите `ctrl` + `v` что бы вставить его (можно и сразу сохранять как `.png` файл)

Comment: Ваш код делает скриншот только видимой части.

Comment: Код делает скрин всего екрана, что тогда Вам нужно?

Comment: Насколько я понял из вопроса ТС, ему нужна опция аналогичная "Capture full size screenshot" из инструментов Chrome.

Comment: @Alex Zab Именно. Нужен скрин всей страницы сайта без скроллом и другого

Comment: Ну тогда просто добавить нажатии кнопки `f11`